# "no projects supported by NuGet in the solution" error in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) , Version 17.3.6.

I got the error message when I try to open "Manage Nuget packages for solution". I have restarted the Visual Studio, no help. I opened Nuget package manager -> Package manager settings. The package source was name: packageseouce, source: https://packageseouce. I changed it to name : nuget.org, source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. It still not working even after restart, rebuild.

My other solutions have no this problem.

Thank you for your help.

Peter

Comment: Isn't the error message self-explanitory?  Do you have a solution open? NuGet doesn't support "open folder". If you have a solution open, what kind of projects do you have open? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved by Tianyu Sun-MSFT.
My solution contains setup project, disabling the project solves the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1356098/no-projects-supported-by-nuget-in-the-solution-err?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1308645#newest-answer-comment

Answer (score 0):

I can produce your situation.

[image]

There are few situations that will cause this:

**1, There doesn't have any project in the solution or the projects that support nuget weren't be indentify:**

[image]

[image]

The first situation needs you to add projects that support nuget package, the second project need you to fix configuration issue.

**2, There doesn't have any project that support nuget package in your solution:**

[image]

**3, Sometimes this is caused by VS Tool.**

In this situation, you can try to repair VS:

[image]

Remove the .vs folder under the solution root folder(.vs directory contains solution information, it will regenerate after the solution reload.):

[image]

Create a new clean solution with nuget-support project.

After the above steps, reopen the original solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't understand what should I do for your 1st and 2nd situation. I have repaired VS, and I removed .vs, bin, obj folders. All of these do not fix the issue. I have several solutions, they are all working with nuget. Also, I found that there is .Nuget folder under the solution folder, a packages.config inside .Nuget. the content is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="NUnit.Runners.Net4" version="2.6.4" />
</packages>

Comment: I just created a new class library project in my solution, then try open the Manage Nuget packages for the solution..., I got same error. I think there is something wrong in the solution level. Maybe missing some file or missing some contents in some config/setting file?

Comment: @peter Hi peter, thanks for your reply, could you please share a screenshot of your solution(Just need to share the solution header and the type of the projects)? And just want to confirm, only this solution has this issue or other solutions also have this issue? :)

Comment: Hi Bowman, Thank you for your help. 
The main project is Windows Application (systray app)
The others are 
Windows Application
Console Application
Class Library
These are all .Net Framework 4.6.1

There is one Class Library, it is .Net standard 2.0